# Camel Split - parallelprocessing = true

Tags: split, parallel-processing, apache-camel

I have question, apache camel I am using `<split parallelprocessing = "true">`. I thought this will do 'n' number of operation at single instance. But problem I am facing is it working on first 10 job and once those completed only next is getting process.

Can anyone point me correct direction, where I am lagging.

Thanks

Edit-1

```
<split id="_split2" parallelProcessing="true">
<pollEnrich timeout="15000"> 
<simple>file://{{homeDirectory}}?fileName=${header.fileName}&amp;readLock=false&amp;noop=true</simple>
</pollEnrich> 
<toD uri="file://{{destDirectory}}//archive?fileName=${property.fileName}"/>
<!--Few more operation-->
</split>
```

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. Is it only working for the first 10 exchanges or only for the first 10 parts of the split? Please add the complete route as well so that we get the full picture.

Comment: I was working for all the exchanges but it processing 10/10 records, FOr example I need to move file from one directory to another. I have scheduler, which will call split function. I have 20 records in source directory, but only 10 is taken to move and after 20 or 30 min gap next set of files are getting moved.

Comment: Okay, but the `file component` is already threaded and has a pool of 10 threads by default. So if your split's only purpose is to process each file in parallel it's unnecessary. Instead look at how you can configure the file component.

Comment: Thank you, you means to say file component will take 10 exchange at single time. So no issue with split, is my understanding is correct.

Comment: Actually I may have confused it a bit. Depending on how your endpoint is configured each poll can theoretically pick up any number of files. If you show us the entire route it will be easier to tell what the problem really is.

Comment: @noMad I have edited my question for your reference

Comment: This still isn't the entire route though. But from what you've shared I can say that your use of `split` doesn't make much sense. You've not provided an argument so I'd be surprised if it does much of anything. The splitter's purpose is to split one `exchange` into smaller pieces for individual processing e.g. an XML file containing multiple orders.